# Is TrueCrypt compatible with FUSE for OS X and SSHFS?

Tags: macos, truecrypt

TrueCrypt 7.1a is already installed on my MacBook with OS X 10.8.4. I plan to install OPENFUSE 2.6 and SSHFS 2.4.1, are they compatible with TrueCrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, OS X 10.8.4-19.0.1 can** use [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) while [osxfuse-2.6.2.dmg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxfuse/files/osxfuse-2.6.2/osxfuse-2.6.2.dmg) and [SSHFS-2.4.1](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/osxfuse/sshfs/SSHFS-2.4.1.pkg) are installed.
Also I **did not observe any** 'installation order issues'.